# Apple Photos.app: Is there a way to select pictures with AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to select photos based on a custom condition using AppleScript.

By select I mean the selection in the browser's UI.

I can query the current selection with `get selection`. But it's a read-only property, i.e. I cannot use `set selection to ...`.

Is there another way to select items with AppleScript, or maybe with some other tricks, provided I know the "media item" I want to select?

Comment: Why are you trying to select different media items? I ask because if you're trying to do something with a group of selected media items, there may be a programatic way to create a list of target media items and preform some action on them without having to select them in the UI.

Comment: I know, I use that for exporting, for instance. But I want to be able to select the items so that I can interactively operate on them instead of having to program the commands for them.

Comment: I see nothing in the standard additions AppleScript dictionary or Photo's AppleScript dictionary that will let you set a selection of media items. That leaves using UI scripting with System Events and considering how nested the objects are in the UI, IMO it's not the way to go and it would probably be less coding to just use what's available in the Photo's AppleScript dictionary for a pure programatic solution. What's left is AppleScriptObjC, which it outside of my wheelhouse.